# Dichotomous independent variables and interpretation of regression output

Tags: regression, stata, categorical-encoding, variable

I am running a regression on stata concerning the association of smoking intervention types upon participant age of first use. The dependent (age) is a discrete variable by age in years, while the independent variables (intervention types) are dichotomous yes/no variables.

They are coded as 1 and 2. 1 being "having received the intervention" and 2 being "has never received the intervention. How might I interpret the results of my coefficients in the context of these independent variables?

Answer (score 0):

Your dichotomous predictor variable is a *factor* or *categorical* variable, and there must be some way of telling stata it is. Alternatively, recode as 1/0, then the interpretation is direct. You **should not** interpret the output from the 1/2 coding, that output is bogus.

There are many similar posts here, one is [Recoding Categorical Variable for multiple regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/432583/recoding-categorical-variable-for-multiple-regression)